# Strange error with date input in angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to set today as the max date in  date input.
But every time i choose today in the date picker, the model value was always undefined. Has someone met the same problem like this?

html code:

```
<form name="myForm" class="item"> 
    <input type="date" ng-model="date" max="{{maxDateStr}}" name="dateInput">

    <p> date： {{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</p>
    <p>myForm.$valid :  {{myForm.$valid}}</p>
    <p>myForm.dateInput.$error.max :  {{myForm.dateInput.$error.max}}</p>
 </form>
```

js code:

```
angular.module('angularApp',[])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.maxDateStr = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    $scope.date = new Date();

});
```

my code on [codepen](http://codepen.io/fenglu09/pen/oXEGxo)

after debug in chrome, i found that when choose the max date, the value pass to NgModelController.$parsers had time e.g. Thu Jul 02 2015 16:54:00 GMT+0800 (CST). When run the max validator it returns false,

angular max validator code:

```
  var maxVal;
  ctrl.$validators.max = function(value) {
    return !isValidDate(value) || isUndefined(maxVal) || parseDate(value) <= maxVal;
  };
```

because the `maxVal` value was `Thu Jul 02 2015 00:00:00`, it returns false.

Comment: your codepen doesn't open. and also, try to put the code in question itself in brief.

Comment: edit your link -> remove space in starting and add : after http

Comment: Saw your code... it is working fine for me... what is the exact problem?

Comment: I'm so sorry for that. The link has changed and can open now

Comment: @RohitKumar But when i choose the max date, the model value was undefined

Comment: use date `$scope.date = new Date(2015, 15, 15)`

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura  thanks, after i use `$scope.date = new Date(2015, 15, 15) `  it works for me.  But there is another problem, the view value was 04/15/2016. I want it to be the string of today.

Comment: @FengLu you mean `$scope.date` variable, you want as today?

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura yes, I want `$scope.date` be initialized to today. And when the page load, the view value is today

Comment: try to add ng internationalization angular js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code with following

```
angular.module('angularApp',[])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.maxDateStr = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    $scope.date = new Date();
});
```

with

```
angular.module('angularApp',[])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.maxDateStr = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    $scope.date = new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(), (new Date()).getMonth(), (new Date()).getDate());
});
```

**Note:** It will create date with `00:00:00` time, so it should perfect working with max validation.